# Google Cloud Function logs showing error icon for Info log types

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am new to google-cloud and to stack driver logging. deployed a python script as cloud function also enabled in-built logging for python. I had set multiples logs based on the execution.

```
logging.info("Cloud fucntion was Triggerred on time {}".format(datetime.utcnow()))
```

While viewing in cloud function logs, i see many, like even the statement above, for which I have set **INFO** as the log level is displayed with **!!** icon which according to the **legends** should be displayed for only error types. [image]

As I am new to this stack-driver logging, I am not sure of the reason, can anyone please explain? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "enabled in-built logging for python"?  In your code, what is "ex" set to?

Comment: there is no ex, i have removed it

Comment: Please provide the expanded version of the logs to see the details and reasons of error message. you can use the [documentation-1](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/quickstart) to understand how to use cloud logging .

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am not able to expand it further,as it is already in expanded version

Comment: Which Python version you are using  ?  In Python 2.7 logs in Stackdriver logging are being automatically correlated, but for Python 3 these logs are no longer automatically correlated [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#logging).In order to implement your desired logging behavior, you can use the Stackdriver Logging client libraries [2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).I also recommend to please check the document [3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs).

Comment: i am using python3.7